# 'socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker' invalid or not found; no module named sgunicorn

Tags: python, pip, gunicorn, nvidia-digits

I can't find any module called 'sgunicorn'. This is my /var/log/digits/digits.log of my NVIDIA DIGITS 4 instance:

```
Error: class uri 'socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker' invalid or not found: 

[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 133, in load_class
    mod = __import__('.'.join(components))
ImportError: No module named sgunicorn
```

These are my pip modules:

```
Cheetah==2.4.4
Cython==0.20.1post0
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SocketIO==0.6.0
Flask-WTF==0.11
Jinja2==2.7.2
Landscape-Client==14.12
M2Crypto==0.21.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.3.0
PyYAML==3.10
Twisted-Core==13.2.0
Twisted-Names==13.2.0
Twisted-Web==13.2.0
WTForms==2.0.1
Werkzeug==0.9.4
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
aws-cfn-bootstrap==1.4
awscli==1.10.66
beautifulsoup4==4.2.1
blinker==1.3
boto3==1.1.1
botocore==1.4.56
certifi==2015.04.28
chardet==2.0.1
circus==0.14.0
cloud-init==0.7.5
colorama==0.2.5
configobj==4.7.2
cvxopt==1.1.4
decorator==3.4.0
docutils==0.12
filelock==2.0.6
futures==2.2.0
gevent==1.0
gevent-socketio==0.3.6
gevent-websocket==0.9.3
greenlet==0.4.2
gunicorn==17.5
gyp==0.1
h5py==2.2.1
html5lib==0.999
iowait==0.2
ipython==1.2.1
itsdangerous==0.22
jmespath==0.9.0
joblib==0.7.1
jsonpatch==1.3
jsonpointer==1.0
leveldb==0.1
lmdb==0.87
lockfile==0.12.2
matplotlib==1.3.1
msgpack-python==0.4.6
networkx==1.8.1
newrelic-api==1.0.4
nose==1.3.1
numexpr==2.2.2
numpy==1.8.2
oauth==1.0.1
openpyxl==1.7.0
pandas==0.13.1
patsy==0.2.1
pexpect==3.1
prettytable==0.7.2
protobuf==2.5.0
psutil==3.4.2
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.66
pycurl==7.19.3
pydot==1.0.28
pygobject==3.12.0
pyinotify==0.9.4
pyparsing==2.0.1
pyserial==2.6
pysmbc==1.0.14.1
pystache==0.5.4
python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-daemon==1.6.1
python-dateutil==2.5.3
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
python-engineio==1.0.3
python-gflags==1.5.1
python-socketio==1.6.0
pytz==2012c
pyzmq==14.0.1
requests==2.2.1
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.4
salt==2016.3.1
scikit-image==0.9.3
scikit-learn==0.14.1
scipy==0.13.3
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.3.1
six==1.10.0
ssh-import-id==3.21
statsmodels==0.5.0
system-service==0.1.6
tables==3.1.1
tornado==4.2.1
urllib3==1.7.1
virtualenv==15.0.3
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlrd==0.9.2
xlwt==0.7.5
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

I've already tried to downgrade some modules but the problem still persists. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Check your package versions: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/digits-4.0/requirements.txt

Comment: Done. The problem persists. Question edited with my pip modules.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. Try this little script to investigate: https://gist.github.com/lukeyeager/1651330a0e317f790b8a32584cc7e23b

Comment: I deleted everything and did manual install. It works now.